# Find out processing/memory capabillities of phone

Tags: android, image-processing, ram

I'm trying to find out the maximal image resolution for processing photos in my app. 
The first version of it is already online, and I got several OutOfMemoryError exception reports already.

Is there a way to determine the available memory, or is there some other strategy to find the best solution (in fact the maximum image resolution) for processing images on different phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your approx. memory limit for your app *(in megabytes)* by using the activity managers [`getMemoryClass()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29) method:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Service.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
int maxMemoryInMb = am.getMemoryClass();
```

You can use that and calucate the maximum sizes of your image(s), this depends on the internal image format of course *(see [Bitmap.Config](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html))*.

Comment: Thanks- good point. Is there some way to release memory of bitmap objects immediately, so I can be sure at each point in time that only the used objects are consuming memory?

Comment: I'd like to answer that with a "maybe". I never wrote an app that required this kind of memory management. Of course you can call `System.gc()` and the like to indicate the garbage collector that this is a good time to run some cleanup. But I believe there are multiple gc runs neccessary to free a bitmap completely. And it's just a indication for the gc, so this might be ignored. If you have some time, watch [this google I/O session](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/memory-management-for-android-apps.html), it's been a while, but I remember it has some useful details.